# Split an array dependent on the array values in Python

Tags: python, arrays, split

I have an array of coordinates like this:

```
array = [[1,6],[2,6],[3,8],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[18,6],[19,5],[17,9],[10,5]]
```

I want to split the array between `6`. and `7`. coordinate `([5,7],[18,6])` because there is a gap in the `X` value there. I want to get two separate arrays, `arr1` and `arr2`, where `arr1` is the values before the split and `arr2` is the values after.

I want to say that if the next `X` value is larger than a difference of `10`, it will append to `arr2`, else `arr1`, something like this:

```
arr1 = []
arr2 = []
for [x,y] in array: 
    if next(x) > 10:
        arr2.append(x,y)
    else:
        arr1.append(x,y)
```

Can someone please help me with this problem?

Comment: The `> 10:` is a hard-coded attempt then, the number `10` isn't relevant, only the split in continuity? What about `[5,6],[5,7]`, this should be ignored too?

Comment: Also, your appends should look like `arr1.append([x,y])` to be consistent with your original list

Comment: Actually it's not clear to me at all why this would only result in two arrays from the example input, the split seems arbitrary.

Comment: Do you just need to split based on index where first difference greater than 10?

Comment: The `10` is a hard-coded attempt, if there is a better way please let me know ;) The array size may change, but there will always be one lagre "jump" in the `x` value somewhere, and this is where I want to split the array.

Comment: Will it be the first largest jump in increasing order or order doesn't matter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
ar = np.array([[1,6],[2,6],[3,8],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[18,6],[19,5],[17,9],[10,5]])

# get differences of x values
dif = ar[1:, 0] - ar[:-1, 0]

# get the index where you first observe a jump
fi = np.where(abs(dif) > 10)[0][0]

ar1 = ar[:fi+1]
ar2 = ar[fi+1:]
```

Then `dif` would be:

```
array([ 1,  1,  1,  1,  0, 13,  1, -2, -7])
```

`fi` would be 5 and `ar1` and `ar2` would be:

```
array([[ 1,  6],
       [ 2,  6],
       [ 3,  8],
       [ 4, 10],
       [ 5,  6],
       [ 5,  7]])
```

and

```
array([[18,  6],
       [19,  5],
       [17,  9],
       [10,  5]]),
```

respectively.

That would also allow you to get all jumps in your data (you would just have to change `fi = np.where(abs(dif) > 10)[0][0]` to `fi = np.where(abs(dif) > 10)[0]`)

Answer (score 3):

This might be what you are looking for

```
array = [[1,6],[2,6],[3,8],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[18,6],[19,5],[17,9],[10,5]]
# Declare two array variables
arr1 = None
arr2 = None
n = len(array)
for i in range(n-1): 
    if abs(array[i][0] - array[i+1][0]) >= 10:
       arr1 = array[:i+1]
       arr2 = array[i+1:]
       break

print arr1
print arr2
```

Comment: How would one do it with respect to the Y value? changing `if abs(array[i][0] - array[i+1][0]) >= 10:` to `if abs(array[0][i] - array[0][i+1]) >= 10:` just returns an `IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: That should return `out of range error` since the range of `for` loop depends on the number of elements in `array`. If you want to deal with Y values, you can write an inner for loop.

Answer (score 3):

If I got your question correctly, you're trying to split the array at the first point where the difference between two subsequent x-values is greater than 10.
You can do that using numpy:

```
import numpy as np
THRESH = 10
array = [[1,6],[2,6],[3,8],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[18,6],[19,5],[17,9],[10,5]]
array = np.asarray(array)
deltas_x = np.abs(array[1:,0] - array[:-1,0])
split_idx = np.where(deltas_x > THRESH)[0][0] + 1
arr1 = array[:split_idx,:]
arr2 = array[split_idx:,:]
```

Note that we need to add 1 to the result of np.where to account for the fact that the `deltas_x` array is 1 value shorter than `array`

Answer (score 2):

Probably easiest to iterate over successive pairs and split as soon as a gap is found:

```
array = [[1,6],[2,6],[3,8],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[18,6],[19,5],[17,9],[10,5]]

for idx, (cur, nxt) in enumerate(zip(array, array[1:])):  # successive pairs and index
    if abs(cur[0] - nxt[0]) > 10:  # compare difference of first items
        arr1, arr2 = array[:idx+1], array[idx+1:]  # split
        break  # no further splits, end the loop now
else:  # no break, keep the original array
    arr1, arr2 = array, []
```

Which gives:

```
>>> arr1
[[1, 6], [2, 6], [3, 8], [4, 10], [5, 6], [5, 7]]
>>> arr2
[[18, 6], [19, 5], [17, 9], [10, 5]]
```

It would be a bit more difficult if you wanted to split several times but this should well in your case.

Answer (score 2):

When comparing consecutive elements I usually use enumerate:

```
array = [[1,6],[2,6],[3,8],[4,10],[5,6],[5,7],[18,6],[19,5],[17,9],[10,5]]
arr1 = list()
arr2 = list()
gap = 10

for index, value in enumerate(array[:-1]): # [:-1] prevents out of range
    if abs(value[0]-array[index+1][0]) >= gap:
        arr1.append(value)
    else:
        arr2.append(value)

arr2.append(array[-1])  # Take into account that the last element needs to be added to one of the arrays.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
arry1 = []
arry2 = []
for i in arry:
    if (i[0] - i[1]) > 10:
        arry1.append(i)
    else:
        arry2.append(i)
```

Comment: Use a comment, not answer

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
prev = array[0][0] 
pos = -1 
for i in range (1, len(array)): 
  if array[i][0] - prev >1: 
    break  
  else:  
    prev = array[i][0]  
if pos != -1:  
  arr1 = array[:pos]  
  arr2 = array[pos:]
```

This should split `array` the way you want. Note that lists are indexed from 0.

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  I should have mentioned that the size of the array may change, but there will always be a gap in the X value somewhere. That is why I want a method to split dependent of the X value.

Comment: This should find the first place in the array where the x values are not continous. Thanks! @Rohan Sadale