# Splitting array of coordinates dependent on the Y value in Python

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array of coordinates, and I would like to split the array into two arrays dependent on the Y value when there is a large gap in the Y value. This post: [Split an array dependent on the array values in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42650289/split-an-array-dependent-on-the-array-values-in-python/42650567?noredirect=1#comment73512131_42650567) does it dependent on the x value, and the method I use is like this:

```
array = [[1,5],[3,5],[6,7],[8,7],[25,25],[26,50],.....]
n = len(array)
for i in range(n-1): 
    if abs(array[i][0] - array[i+1][0]) >= 10:
       arr1 = array[:i+1]
       arr2 = array[i+1:]
```

I figured that when I want to split it dependent on the Y value I could just change:

`if abs(array[i][0] - array[i+1][0])` to `if abs(array[0][i] - array[0][i+1])`

This does not work and I get `IndexError: list index out of range.`

I'm quite new to coding and I'm wondering why this does not work for finding gap in Y value when it works for finding the gap in the X value?

Also, how should I go about splitting the array depending on the Y value?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: abs(array[i][1] - array[i+1][1]) <<--- mind the indexing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to switch to this:

```
array = [[1,5],[3,5],[6,7],[8,7],[25,25],[26,50]]
n = len(array)
for i in range(n-1): 
    if abs(array[i][1] - array[i+1][1]) >= 10:

       arr1 = array[:i+1]
       arr2 = array[i+1:]
```